How to join one prometheus metric with another?
I have two metrics: one called template_details_total that publishes details about a template such as its name and ID e.g., template_details_total{id='1', name='t_name'}, and another called template_status_total that publishes status codes corresponding to the template e.g. template_status_total{id='1', status='success'}.
I need a PromQL query that joins these two metrics to display both the name and status together on a Grafana dashboard. Each ID in template_details_total corresponds to a unique name, but an ID in template_status_total can have multiple statuses.
I attempted the following PromQL query:
template_details_total * on(id) group_left(status) sum by (status (template_status_total) 

However, it resulted in the error:

“Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {} on the right-hand side of the operation.”


When using group_left, the label being added (status) should be present in the right-hand metric (template_status_total) but it is not used correctly in the sum by (status) aggregation. It attempts to sum the metrics by status before performing the join.
Correct query should be:
template_status_total * on(id) group_left(name) template_details_total
